# Caption, Description or Name for https://schema.org/ImageObject

Tags: schema.org

What is the correct `itemprop` for `ImageObject`?

On https://schema.org/ImageObject at the top there is `caption` for Image, but in the example they only show `description`.

I also found an example with `itemprop="name"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are valid properties to be used here.

`Caption` is specific to an `ImageObject`.

`ImageObject` inherits properties from `Thing`, which includes `Description` (and `Name`).

All are valid properties that can go on an `ImageObject`. I agree it's tough to tell the difference between `Description` and `Caption` in this case and the examples on [schema.org](https://schema.org) could be better here.

As far as my interpretation of how it can be used, think of a picture of a couple on a beach:

- Your `Caption` would be something such as "A couple enjoys their time on a beach in the Bahamas"
- `Description` would be "A picture of a couple on a beach".
- `Name` would be just a general title of the photo (or even the filename of the photo).

It's also worth noting that according to the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), neither `Caption` or `Description` are required, but both are accepted.